# build dynamic documents from a Textdatabase

Tags: import, database

I need a dynamic solution to produce questionnaires from a database of questions which gets updated from time to time. I thought of LaTeX for set out the layout but the question is whether LaTeX can import specified fields of an Acces or Excel or whatsoever external "database".

I also thought about WORD Macros and .NET programming, but I preferred LaTeX.

Comment: Is there a possibility to export in a plain text format, for example `.csv`? This is readily handled by TeX (provided the file is not too big!), but direct access to binary structures realistically requires LuaTeX.

Comment: Maybe you can use [SQLTeX](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sqltex). Alternatively, you might be interested in the [@EASE system](http://acrotex.net/atease_index.php) which is part of the `AcroTeX`tools.

Answer (score 3):

If "whatsoever external database" may be a plain text file like this `data.dat` example:

```
Mr.
Peter
Smith
Newtown Road, Los Angeles, USA
209 \$


Ms. 
Maria 
Rossi
Regina Elena, 113, Milano, Italy
145 \euro
```

Where simply the field separators are carriage returns, then  you can merge with a LaTeX document with the `textmerg` package as in this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{textmerg} 
\begin{document}

\Fields{\Mr\Name\SurName\Address\Donation} 

{\bf Cots of donations to some good cause:}
\vspace{2ex}

\Merge{data.dat}{

\begin{tabular}{r|l}
Person & {\bf \Mr\ \Name\  \SurName }\\
Address & {\bf \Address }\\
Cost & {\bf \Donation } \\
\end{tabular}
\vspace{2ex}

}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at nlatexdb, I found it very useful.

http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nlatexdb