# Inserting lyx into lyx?

Tags: lyx, automation

Let's say I send mass-email to many people in many parts of the world.

I want to make customized pdf file for people of different countries, gender, occupation.

Can I make US.lyx, UK.lyx, France.lyx, man.lyx, woman.lyx, teacher.lyx, doctor.lyx, etc

And for a French man who is a doctor, I make a lyx document that calls in France.lyx, man.lyx, doctor.lyx into one lyx file.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is <kbd>Insert</kbd> → <kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>Child document</kbd> → Include type: <kbd>Input</kbd>,  but explore also <kbd>Insert→ Branch</kbd> to do that easier from the  same file.

What you want really probably some package to make personalized documents based on a database, as [textmerg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71322/11604) or  [datatool](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46425/11604).

Comment: Thank you! Just one problem while using child document was that, if I compile it using pdflatex, there always is one blank. So if child document contains "Hello" then the parent document will contain "Hello " with one blank in the end. How can I fix this?

Comment: I wrote more details on what's happening: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569226/child-document-embedding-in-lyx-creates-a-redundant-blank-in-the-end