# Child document embedding in lyx creates a redundant blank in the end

Tags: pdftex, lyx, pdf, input

Child document created by lyx is this.

```
%% LyX 2.3.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

The parent document has this child document.

```
%% LyX 2.3.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{onehalfspace}
\input{Hello.tex}.
\end{onehalfspace}
\end{document}
```

Then, if I convert using pdflatex, I don't get "Hello." I get a redundant blank so I get "Hello ."

How can I fix this?

Comment: Put the dot `.` in the child document

Comment: @DG'  Thank you. This is good as a partial solution. Is it possible to just fix it more fundamentally? By the way, "Hello" was just an example. I will actually write more words after "Hello" If dot is in the child document, then the next words would have to follow immediate without a blank.

Comment: I don't know if there is anything to fix, because I don't believe it's broken. Your example won't compile, by the way, since `Hello.tex` contains code, that is only allowed in the preamble. But more importantly: The file contains not only the text, but also an end-of-line character, that means that everything after the input statement starts effectively on a new line.

Comment: @DG The example will compile in LyX with the original parent file (with .lyx extension).  LyX will take care that the child file (Hello.lyx) will be not exported in Hello.tex as a complete document, but only the contents. What the OP has showed in a code preview or the export of Hello.lyx as a stand-alone file, not the real result compiling the parent file.

Comment: You can try to use [`\minput`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87202/29873), but I don't know, if Lxy will like it.

Comment: @user1849133 `\input{}` add only what it is in the .tex file,  but in LaTeX the end of lines are spaces. Build a tex file with   `echo"x" > test.tex` and then test what happen with `\input{test.tex}.`  (Note: the extension is not mandatory): The result is `x .` (with a space). Now make the file with  `echo"x%" > test.tex`  and check again. Now the end of line is part of the comment, so is not included as a space.

Comment: @Fran Thank you but I can't understand. I don't know what echo means. I tested anyways. I converted Hello.lyx to Hello.txt. Then in the parent file, I did input{Hello.tex}. Lyx can't even compile this file

Comment: @user1849133 `echo"x" > test.tex` is a basic method  from the system prompt to make  a plain text file that only have the character "x" , but you can use also any plain text editor for that. Your `Hello.tex` file  **must** have only the word "Hello", not all the code that you posted exporting from lyx directly. Then will always work.  Lyx can input lyx files (that are converted in the background to **non**-stand-alone .tex files) or non-stand-alone .tex files directly, and they  will work if there are no wrong code inside, but nest a stand-alone .tex files is completely wrong.