# Create a function that generates a letter?

Tags: automation

I have to write many letters where each time I have to modify just the names, dates and address, but it is always the same content.

A short version would be something like "Dear [name], from [address] you have to present yourself at [time] [date]."

Is there anyway to automate this? I would just like to insert the right fields for Latex to create the letter from a template.

Comment: Could you set the letter as a new command with four variables?

Comment: @Jay could you provide an example?

Comment: I... can't find any tutorial to create new LaTeX macro on this site, but you should be able to find plenty on the Internet (hopefully).

Comment: Check the `datatool` package. You simply create a CSV file with the fields and then read it to print what you want.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71322/11604

Comment: @Mauricio I don't write letters. What I was thinking of was a new command which has several variables for the items in the letter which vary. The command would be a completely formatted letter with the variables would be [name], [address], etc. When you call the command the information would be the parameters of the command. Fran'a comment seems to be a better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I like to do it like this, using the `datatool` package** (like also suggested in the comments) **:**

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrlttr2}  
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}        
\setkomavar{date}{\today}
\setkomavar{subject}{Very Important Letter}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Tom}
\setkomavar{fromaddress} {%
    My Company\\
    Company Way 42\\
    1337~Corporatetown%
}   

\DTLloaddb{list}{addresses.csv}
\DTLforeach{list}{\first=Firstname,\last=Lastname,\address=Street,
    \town=Town,\postal=Postal}{% start of loop
\begin{letter}{\first~\last \\ \address \\ \postal~\town}%
\opening{Dear \first~\last,}%

    some text   
    
    some more text

        \closing{Best regards}

\end{letter}
} % end of for loop
\end{document}
```

Then I have all the addresses in a separate `addresses.csv`, like this:

```
Firstname,Lastname,Street,Postal,Town
John,Doe,Example Street 1, 12345, North Pole
Jane,Doe,Example Street 2, 12345, North Pole
```

The resulting letter is probably not styled like you prefer, of course. But you have the whole world of KOMA options at your disposal, just check the [KOMA manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)!

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat simpler approach is to remember that you can have multiple `letter` environments in a single document. Thus you could write something like this:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\address{YOUR ADDRESS GOES HERE}
\signature{YOUR SIGNATURE INFO HERE}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myletter}{mmmm}
  {
    \begin{letter}{#1}
    \opening{Dear #2:}
    Please present yourself at the #3 at #4 on #5.
    \closing{Threateningly,}
    \end{letter}
  }

\begin{document}
\myletter{Julius Caesar\\Subura\\Rome}{Julius}{Curia of Pompey}{3:00PM}{15 March 44 BC}
\myletter{Gaius Germanicus\\Temple of Castor and Pollux\\Rome}{Caligula}{Cryptoporticus}{3:00PM}{24 January 41}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way with the `listofitems` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\letterdata{
Sam, Main Street, 3 p.m., 14 April 2022\\
Lisa, Elm St., 1500, 25 December 2022}

\newcommand\stencil{
\noindent Dear <data>,

Please report to our <data> location at <data> on <data>.

\noindent kind regards,\\
The Management}

\setsepchar{\\/,}
\readlist\letteritems{\letterdata}
\setsepchar{<data>}
\readlist\stencilitems{\stencil}

\begin{document}

\foreachitem\z\in\letteritems[]{%
  \foreachitem\zz\in\stencilitems[]{%
    \zz 
    \ifnum\zzcnt<\listlen\stencilitems[]\letteritems[\zcnt,\zzcnt]\fi%
  }%
  \par\bigskip\noindent\hrulefill\par\bigskip
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need to use the data items out of sequence, or repeatedly, then this variation would suffice:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\letterdata{
Sam, Main Street, 3 p.m., 14 April 2022\\
Lisa, Elm St., 1500, 25 December 2022}

\newcommand\stencil{%
\noindent Dear <data>{1},

Please report to our <data>{2} location at <data>{3} on <data>{4}.

Thank you again, <data>{1}, for your willingness to assist us in
  this matter.

\noindent kind regards,\\
The Management}

\setsepchar{\\/,}
\readlist*\letteritems{\letterdata}
\setsepchar{<data>}
\readlist\stencilitems{\stencil}

\newcommand\fillinthedata[2]{\letteritems[#1,#2]}
\newtoks\lettertoks
\newcommand\addtolettertoks[1]{%
      \lettertoks\expandafter{\the\lettertoks#1}}
\newcommand\xaddtolettertoks[1]{%
      \lettertoks\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter
      \the\expandafter\lettertoks#1}}
\begin{document}

\foreachitem\z\in\letteritems[]{%
  \lettertoks{}%
  \foreachitem\zz\in\stencilitems[]{%
    \xaddtolettertoks{\zz}%
    \ifnum\zzcnt<\listlen\stencilitems[]\relax
      \addtolettertoks{\fillinthedata}%
      \xaddtolettertoks{\expandafter{\zcnt}}%
    \fi%
  }%
  \the\lettertoks
  \par\bigskip\noindent\hrulefill\par\bigskip
}

\end{document}
```

[image]